# How to create custom initilizers with Cocoa Realm

Tags: ios, cocoa, swift, realm

I have a swift project with Realm in it where I would like to store objects using RLMObject, however I cannot create a custom init, as it will throw an error.

I Have tried

```
import Foundation
import Realm

class Foo: RLMObject {

dynamic var First: String = ""
dynamic var Last: String = ""

init(first: String, last: String) {
    super.init()
    self.First = first
    self.Last = last
}

override init(object: AnyObject?) {
    super.init(object:object)
}

override init(object value: AnyObject!, schema: RLMSchema!) {
    super.init(object: value, schema: schema)
}

override init(objectSchema: RLMObjectSchema) {
    super.init(objectSchema: objectSchema)
}
}
```

Which was suggested [here](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1101)

Comment: Have you tried adding `public override init(realm: RLMRealm, schema: RLMObjectSchema, defaultValues: Bool) {
        super.init(realm: realm, schema: schema, defaultValues: defaultValues)
    }`

Comment: This did not work, it says the initializer does not override a designated initializer from its superclass

Comment: What version of Realm are you using? What error are you seeing?

Comment: My realm version is 0.90 and the error is fatal error: use of unimplemented initializer 'init()'

Comment: Aren't you missing `override init() { super.init() }`. In the example you gave, you have to override all of them for custom inits to work.

Comment: Right, but then how can I pass any custom initializers